# Confusion about Function.prototype.bind()

Tags: javascript, bind, ecmascript-5, partial-application

I'm a huge fan of ES5's `Function.prototype.bind` and currying arguments (basically creating default arguments for functions).

I was fooling around with that a bit, but I can't for the life of me figure out my own construct anymore. This is my playground:

```
function hello( arg1, arg2 ) {
    console.log('hello()');
    console.log('"this" is: ', this);
    console.log('arguments: ', arguments);
}

var foo = Function.prototype.call.bind( hello,{what: 'dafuq'}, 2 );
foo( 42 );
```

The log output for this is as follows:

```
hello()
"this" is: Object{ what="dafuq" }
arguments: [2,42]
```

But I don't understand how on earth the `{what: 'dafuq'}` object makes its way as a reference for the `this` within `foo`. As far as I understand it, we are creating a *bound call* to `Function.prototype.call`. Lets check the MDN synopsis for `.bind()` quickly:

```
fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

so, `thisArg` for `.call` is the `hello` function, followed by the arguments list. Basically what happens is this

```
Function.prototype.call.call( hello, {what: 'dafuq'}, 2);
```

...uuhhh now my brain hurts a little. I think I have an idea now what happens, but please someone find nice solid words to explain it in detail.

- **how `{what: 'dafuq'}` becomes the `this reference`**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But I don't understand how on earth the `{what: 'dafuq'}` object makes its way as a reference for the this within foo

It's because `foo` is effectively the `call` method with the `hello` function bound as the calling context, and that object bound as the first argument. The first argument of `.call` *sets the calling context of its calling context*. Since you've bound it, it means that object always be the calling context.

---

Put it this way...

You've bound the calling context of `.call` to `hello`.

This is effectively the same as doing...

```
   hello.call();
// or...
// Function.prototype.call.call(hello);
```

You've also bound the first argument of `.call` to `{what: "dafuq"}`, so this is effectively the same as doing...

```
hello.call({what: "dafuq"});
// or...
// Function.prototype.call.call(hello, {what: "dafuq"});
```

And finally, you've bound the second argument of `.call` to `2`, so this is effectively the same as doing...

```
hello.call({what: "dafuq"}, 2);
// or...
// Function.prototype.call.call(hello, {what: "dafuq"}, 2);
```

Comment: yes `foo` is the call method, but we never call `foo.call( thisArg )` right ? we just call it directly by `()`. I don't get it :p

Comment: @jAndy: You bound the first argument of `.call` using `.bind` to your object. So since this "version" of `.call` has a bound first argument, it'll always use that as the calling context.

Comment: the bound "version" of `.call()` should have `hello` as thisArg, no ? After that, we execute that bound `.call()` just passing in formal parameters. Doh, well might be I'm just mentally blocked here, still figuring it.

Comment: @jAndy: You've bound the calling context of `.call` to `hello`. This is effectively the same as doing `hello.call()`. You've bound the first argument of call to `{what: "dafuq"}`. So this is effectively the same as `hello.call({what: "dafuq"})`. And finally, you've bound the second argument of `.call` to `2`, so this is effectively the same as `hello.call({what: "dafuq"}, 2)`

Comment: @jAndy: You're welcome. I'm updating my answer with this explanation.

Answer (score 8):

You're not calling `.bind(thisArg, args)`, but
`Function.prototype.bind.call(thisArgUsedByCall, thisArgUsedByBind, argument)`.

A different way to show what happens:

```
// thisArgUsedByCall is a function
Function.prototype.call(thisArgUsedByCall, ...)   // does the same as:
thisArgUsedByCall.bind(thisArgUsedByBind, argument);
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that bind consumes the first argument and uses it as *this*, but then call consumes *its* first argument (which was bind's second argument).

Bind works like this:

```
fun.bind(thisArg, argArgs...)(x, y, ...)
```

becomes

```
fun(argArgs..., x, y, ....) // this = thisArg
```

So

```
foo( 42 )
```

is

```
Function.prototype.call.bind( hello, { what: 'dafuq' }, 2 ) ( 42 )
```

which becomes

```
Function.prototype.call({ what: 'dafuq' }, 2, 42) // this = hello
```

Call works like this:

```
fun.call(thisArg, argArgs)
```

Becomes

```
fun(argArgs) // this = thisArg
```

so

```
call({ what: 'dafuq' }, 2, 42) // this = hello
```

becomes

```
hello(2, 42) // this = { what: 'dafuq' }
```

Comment: *"(I don't know where that 5 comes from)"* - Which five?

Comment: Looks like it got fixed - it was a typo in the main post. Edited my response in return.